# Invoking/calling a modal using a "ontouchstart" event

Tags: html, modal-dialog, ontouchstart

In a button, a modal is called using data-target of a button, but here since I have a touch screen I want to use ontouchstart (when touched on button, not clicked) to call the modal.

Any suggestion how can I implement this?

This is how I am calling the modal currently: (modal id is myModal)

Please suggest how can I call the div using touch functionality.

Answer (score 0):

finally I invokes a modal using a function of calling modal.
step1: called the function : ontouchstart=myfunction()
step2: called the modal in the function
myfunction(){$scope.openModa = function(){$('#myModalname').modal('show');};}